# Selenium Chrome driver - SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

I am trying to type my first GUI test in pycharm with selenium.

I installed selenium by cmd 
raport:

> C:>pip install selenium
>   Requirement already satisfied: selenium in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (3.141.0)
>   Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from selenium) (1.24.1)

Then I wrote some code in pycharm:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Users\Admin\Desktop")
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FFDDN1C1MEQ");
```

And that is what happened when I clicked start :

> File "C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/test.py", line 3
>       driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Users\Admin\Desktop")
>                                ^
>   SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

win.10
I don't know what I am doing wrong. 
Thanks for any help and have a good day.

edit:
Yes, thanks it works.
I have another error now:

```
C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Backslashes in Python are escaping characters.
When you are going to use Windows path's make sure to use a raw string, to prevent Python trying to escape the string:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\chromedriver.exe")
```

Comment: Good point, yet I have never had an issue with regular string... I think his issue was just with the `chromedriver.exe`. Now I'll know if I have any issue in the future just to use raw string...

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the error the problem is in line 3.

What you need is to specify the path to your chromedriver.exe

Just change it to `driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\your path to chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")`

As for your second issue, it seems you don't have selenium installed:

Just run `pip install selenium` in your CMD (you need `pip` too)

For installing `pip` see [here](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/install-pip-for-python/).

For installing selenium see [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html).

Hope you find this helpful!

Comment: i have installed selenium like that:
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts>pip install selenium

and rep:
Requirement already satisfied: selenium in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (3.141.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from selenium) (1.24.1)

Comment: do you have two versions of python? 2.7 , 3_+

Comment: you are run within a `venv` make sure you have it installed there too, you are using PyCharm so you can just add selenium there in the settings/Project Interpreter click on the + and add selenium...

Comment: Yes, settings helped me Thanks :-)